# Adding LUA module to nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I rpm installed nginx 1.12 on a redhat 7.5 server and It also has LUA 5.1.4 
I downloaded lua-nginx-module-0.10.13 tar ball and put it under /etc/nginx/modules, but I am not able to run nginx with LUA auth file.

I also have openresty under /opt/openresty/ ..

http://openresty.org/en/installation.html
I followed the "make" method here.

Unfortunately this server doesnt have access to the internet so I cant install stuff from git which slows this down considerably. I am not sure how to add the module here. Any comments would be helpful.

This is what my nginx config looks like ..

```
server
{
    listen 80;

    access_log  /opt/elk/logs/nginx/access.log  main;

    #auth_basic "admin";
    #auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/passwd";

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;

        keepalive_timeout 300s;

        #auth_basic on;
        auth_basic "admin";
        auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/passwd";

        access_by_lua_file '/etc/nginx/authorized.lua';
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html
    {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

The lua_access_file is causing an error

nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "access_by_lua_file" Is there some "include" I need to define in the config to get rid of this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am breaking down your problem into the small task, as per question and my understanding.

**1) The error clearly says that you have not install Lua-nginx-module properly.**

[Lua-nginx-module documentation](https://tecadmin.net/install-rpm-file-on-linux/)

**2) The server does not have access to the internet so cannot download from git.**
*

- Assuming you are doing ssh into your machine from windows. So, please
  check below link to copy the files from windows to Linux.

  [Installing/Accessing via WinSCP](https://intranet.cs.hku.hk/csintranet/contents/technical/howto/winscp.jsp)
- 

[how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh)

- this step will get all the necessary files on your server.

**3) Steps to install  nginx with lua-nginx-module.**

- **lua nginx module compatibility check.**

  ```
   Nginx Compatibility
       The latest version of this module is compatible with the following versions of Nginx:

       1.13.x (last tested: 1.13.6)
       1.12.x
       1.11.x (last tested: 1.11.2)
       1.10.x
       1.9.x (last tested: 1.9.15)
       1.8.x
       1.7.x (last tested: 1.7.10)
       1.6.x

       Nginx cores older than 1.6.0 (exclusive) are not supported.
  ```

  [referance document for nginx compatibility](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#nginx-compatibility)
- **Prerequisites**

  ```
  **- Centos/RHEL**[**In case if internet is working in your server**].

   yum install -y wget unzip gcc make openssl-devel pcre-devel zlib-devel
  ```

  **- Downloading .rpm package manually and installing.**

1. Search the prerequisites from the RPM resource site

   - [RPM resource site](https://tecadmin.net/install-rpm-file-on-linux/)
2. Copy the file in your Linux box

   - Please refer above point (2)"**The server does not have access to the internet so cannot download from git**".

   3. Install with the following command.

      ```
        rpm -i rpm-package-name
      ```

   [Install-rpm-file-on-linux](https://tecadmin.net/install-rpm-file-on-linux/)

**- Tarball installation for prerequisites.**

```
 - [Installing gcc from source code ][6]         Similarly,you can look for
          other prerequistes.
```

- **Downloading the source**

  ```
   $ rm -fr /tmp/nginx-build  
   $ mkdir /tmp/nginx-build
   $ cd /tmp/nginx-build

   $ wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.13.0.tar.gz

   $ wget http://luajit.org/download/LuaJIT-2.0.4.tar.gz

   $ wget -O nginx_devel_kit.tar.gz https://github.com/simpl/ngx_devel_kit/archive/v0.3.0.tar.gz

   $ wget -O nginx_lua_module.tar.gz https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/archive/v0.10.8.tar.gz
  ```
- **Extracting**

  ```
    $ tar xvf LuaJIT-2.0.4.tar.gz

    $ tar xvf nginx-1.11.10.tar.gz

    $ tar xvf nginx_devel_kit.tar.gz

    $ tar xvf nginx_lua_module.tar.gz
  ```
- **Building LuaJIT**

  To build Nginx with LuaJIT, we need to build LuaJIT first. This is as simple as a make command

  ```
      $ cd /tmp/nginx-build/LuaJIT-2.0.4
      $ make install
       ==== Building LuaJIT 2.0.4 ====
       make -C src
       make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/nginx/LuaJIT-2.0.4/src'
       ...
       ...
       ln -sf luajit-2.0.4 /usr/local/bin/luajit
       ==== Successfully installed LuaJIT 2.0.4 to /usr/local ====
  ```
- **Building Nginx**

  ```
       $ cd /tmp/nginx-build/nginx-1.11.10
       $ LUAJIT_LIB=/usr/local/lib LUAJIT_INC=/usr/local/include/luajit-2.0 \
       ./configure \
       --user=nobody                          \
       --group=nobody                         \
       --prefix=/etc/nginx                   \
       --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx           \
       --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf     \
       --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid         \
       --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock       \
       --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
       --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
       --with-http_gzip_static_module        \
       --with-http_stub_status_module        \
       --with-http_ssl_module                \
       --with-pcre                           \
       --with-file-aio                       \
       --with-http_realip_module             \
       --without-http_scgi_module            \
       --without-http_uwsgi_module           \
       --without-http_fastcgi_module ${NGINX_DEBUG:+--debug} \
       --with-cc-opt=-O2 --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib' \
       --add-module=/tmp/nginx/ngx_devel_kit-0.3.0 \
       --add-module=/tmp/nginx/lua-nginx-module-0.10.8
       $ make install
  ```
- **Syntanx Check**

  ```
    $ nginx -t
       nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
       nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
  ```
- **Nginx Lua Testing**

  *As per you nginx file.

  ```
    location /
   {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;

   keepalive_timeout 300s;

   #auth_basic on;
   auth_basic "admin";
   auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/passwd";

   access_by_lua_file '/etc/nginx/authorized.lua'; }
  ```
- **Reload / restart nginx**

  ```
       systemctl nginx restart
       systemctl nginx reload.
  ```

[how-to-reload-nginx-systemctl-or-nginx-s](https://superuser.com/questions/710986/how-to-reload-nginx-systemctl-or-nginx-s)

Comment: Thank you, I was following these steps when I had a run at it the first time, I was able to gather the relevant files and start to compile but I was having issues with the command on "building nginx" previously. I will give this another try.

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus  Yes, I totally understand building "Lua-nginx-module" is bit tricky and It does not provide expected results sometimes. I too faced many issues and drafted this after several attempts. It worked for me, give it a try and  Do let us know, how it goes for you.

Comment: @Akshaybarahate, I faced error for make install
/home/nginx-build/lua-nginx-module-0.10.8/src/ngx_http_lua_headers.c:227:15: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘ngx_buf_t * {aka struct ngx_buf_s *}’ from type ‘ngx_chain_t {aka struct ngx_chain_s}’
             b = hc->busy[i];
               ^
objs/Makefile:1446: recipe for target 'objs/addon/src/ngx_http_lua_headers.o' failed
make[1]: *** [objs/addon/src/ngx_http_lua_headers.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nginx-build/nginx-1.19.3'
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2

Answer (score 6):

Now in most Operating Systems (e.g. Ubuntu, etc) Lua support for Nginx can be enabled by installing the `libnginx-mod-http-lua` package. e.g:

```
sudo apt install libnginx-mod-http-lua
```

This package includes the dynamic library and the corresponding `load_module` directive in `/usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-lua.conf` which is usually enabled when the package is installed (by softlinking it into the `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/` directory).

Comment: This saved me from installing resty on raspberry 32bit with debian. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are running nginx with docker you can just follow the [instructions](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/tree/master/modules) on the [docker-nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx) github repository.

In your `nginx-conf` make sure to also load the module by adding

```
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_stream_lua_module.so;
```

Answer (score 1):

Akshay barahate's answer is long and comprehensive.
However to answer your question

> Is there some "include" I need to define in the config to get rid of this ?

Try adding

```
load_module "ngx_http_lua_module.so"
```

The package name may vary, the above file name is derived from an ubuntu 18.04 installation from package.
(Usually you find your modules in /usr/share/nginx/modules)

Note: If you compiled nginx from source (which seems to be the recommended way to get lua running), pathes and filenames can vary.

Happy codin'.