# Adding lua module to nginx dynamically

Tags: nginx, lua

I have tried the installation steps for lua module mentioned here
http://openresty.org/en/getting-started.html

```
resty -e 'print("hello, world")'
```

works

But when i try to restart nginx i get the following error

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "content_by_lua_block" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:11
```

Configuration file is same as mentioned in the link above.

Nginx was install using apt-get 
Output of current nginx -V

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-FIJPpj/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53005072/5449500 Checkout my old answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding LUA module to nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357732/adding-lua-module-to-nginx)

Comment: @Akshaybarahate I already have nginx installed. I did see your answer. It is very comprehensive but i am not sure which point applies to my scenario as i already have nginx installed and do not want to reinstall nginx.

Comment: how you installed the nginx? Using tarball approach or direct  command like yum and apt

Comment: Add OS information please

Comment: I installed nginx on Ubuntu using sudo apt-get install -y nginx

Comment: So you didn't installed openresty(nothing but prebuild nginx image).
Means no lua installed.

are you sure you don't want uninstall current nginx?

Because if uninstall and follow those steps it solve issue in no time.

Adding lua to nginx is troublesome and not straight forward

Comment: We already have nginx installed in live environments, so the first preference is not to reinstall nginx if that is even possible.

Comment: Let's see how can we solve this. Please add the output of this in your question `nginx -V command (upper-case V)`

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus/ have you tired this